# Type mismatch. Required: ContentResolver! Found: Int

Tags: android, kotlin

l want to change the meaning of a word using list view adapte in my app l want to add language to my app use string, lang English and Arabic l want to use those resources in my list adapte because I used list view in my app

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false)

    val code = view.findViewById(R.id.code_id) as AppCompatTextView



    code.text = list[position].code

    if (code.equals("scheduled")) {
        getString(R.string.scheduled).toString(code)
    }




    return view as View
}
```

l got error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ContentResolver!
Found:
Int
```

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code. This code does not seem to involve anything related to `ContentResolver` or even `int`. The only error I can see is the line `if (code.equals("scheduled"))` that must be changed to `if (code.text.equals("scheduled"))`

Comment: Also this: `getString(R.string.scheduled).toString(code)` does not compile, right?

Comment: @forpas since it's Kotlin, it should actually be `if (code.text == "scheduled")`.

Comment: @TheWanderer true, but surely not `code.equals("scheduled")`.

Comment: I don't understand what this code is supposed to be doing. Are you trying to set the text of `code` to "scheduled" if it already equals "scheduled"?

Comment: @TheWanderer yes this what l want

Comment: Why would you set the text to what it already is?

Comment: l want them to arabic language useing string resources

Comment: @forpas yes does not compile

Comment: You don't need to do all his rigamarole if all you want tot do is have it pick the correct translated string. Is the text value (for the `code_id` view) set by the user, or by code?

Answer (score 1):

his working fine on this way

```
  if (code.text == ("scheduled")) {
        code.setText(R.string.scheduled)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that your naming style leads to confusion.

In your `if (code.equals("scheduled"))` you are likely trying to check the value of the `code` property of the list item. What is happening instead is that you are comparing the `code` [AppCompatText]View with a string.

This is one way of doing it.

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)

    val codeView = view.findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.code_id)


    getItem(position)?.run {
        codeView.text = when (code) {
            "scheduled" -> context.getString(R.string.scheduled_text)
            else -> code
        }
    }
    return view
}
```

This is also the second time today I've seen someone inflate a layout in getView. Please read this:

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling#ViewHolder

I've extended an [example I put up on GitHub](https://github.com/andre-artus/ExtendArrayAdapter/) (in answer to a different question) so that it will also showcase contextual translation.